# Dependency Injection in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning about Dependency Injection and trying to use it in a simple nodejs app. This application has to fetch some data with an external API. Using DI in that case was simple, I just added the dependency as a parameter of the function and it worked like a charm.

```
async function foo(URL,get_data){
    var bar = await get_data(URL);

    return bar;
}
```

When the application is running, `get_data` would be the function that does the real request and when unit testing my app it would be a dummy function.

How do I apply this same methodology for ExpressJS?

I want it to access the database when is using the application and dummy data when it is testing, but I can't figure out how because I'm not dealing with properties of functions anymore.

In this example:

```
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var db = require('./model/db')

app.get('/users',(req,res) =>{
    db.get_users(function(users){
        res.send(users);
    })
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening to port: ${PORT}`));

module.exports = app;
```

I need to use the real db when the server is running and a mock one when testing with supertest.

```
// index.text.js
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('index');

describe("GET /user", function(){
    it('should respond with a json', function(done){
        request(app)
            .get('/users')
            .expect('Content-Type',/json/)
            .expect(200,done);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try writing an example (even totally wrong one) and attach it to your question. It will help people understand what you need.

Comment: There are a variety of mechanisms. You’d probably want to explore other options like dummy data and mocking/stubbing instead, though.

Comment: "I need to use the real db when the server is running and a mock one when testing with supertest." Using a "test" db can be a valid approach for you?

Comment: the idea was to isolate the testing from accessing the database. I was thinking about something along the lines of using placeholder data (a couple of json's) for it.